# List every DIV element with the same ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I list all DIV elements with the same ID?  For example:

```
<div id="div3">
```

I tried the following method but I only get the first DIV with the same ID:

```
    jQuery('.div_class').hover(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();})
```

Comment: Are you duplicating the ids? how does your html look.

Comment: You only get the first ID because...ID's must be **unique**

Comment: id's are supposed to be unique. Fix it.

Comment: But can I do with  jQuery("[id=.....]")

Comment: Jquery follows the rules and will only give you back the first one. The method is set up to only return a single value not a list. Use a class.

Comment: @blek then why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the same id for multiple dom object it can cause problems that's why dom elements are suppose to have different ids. if you want to select multiple items give them all the same class

Comment: I agree duplicate id's are bad and should be avoided, but you definitely can select them.

Answer (score 0):

The point of an `id` is to be unique. It is an identifier for the element.

If you have many elements that you want to group, use a `class` instead.